# PowerShell O365 API List Child Folders

Tags: rest, powershell, outlook, office365, directory

I am trying to get a list of all child folders within a specific folder in my O365 Outlook account. So far, I have the following script, where I am explicitly entering the Parent Folder ID and the running a query on the child folders. It is working, but only returning the top 10 results when there are around 80 folders that I would expect to see.

Any suggestions on returning all child items would be appreciated! Thanks.

```
$username = "<username@domain.com>"
$password = "<password here>" | convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password

$parentID = "AAMkAGMyMmFhMWY4LThjYjYtNGUzZS1hYTUxLWIxZGU1ZGRkMjIzMwAuAAAAAABqWqwE0q0sRaLyviyai0vAAQCJ2HjgFyYWQrD2lnZOADX0AAHwCF4IAAA="

$apiURL = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/folders/$($parentID)/childfolders?top=500"

$query = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiURL -Credential $cred | ForEach-Object{$_.Value} 

$folders = $query | Select-Object -Property DisplayName

$results = foreach($folder in $folders){
    $DisplayName = $folder.DisplayName

    Write-Host "CLIENT: $DisplayName"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a GET request on a **Messages** or **ChildFolders** property, a collection, or a **CalendarView** returns ten entries (maximum 50). You can change this behavior by using the **$top** query parameter to set a maximum number.

Here is an example that demostarte to get the all data from the collection via using the ‘@odata.nextLink’:

```
$accessToken=''
$apiURL='https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/folders?$select=displayname&$top=2'


do{

$query=invoke-restmethod -Uri $apiURL -Headers @{Authorization=("bearer {0}" -f $accessToken)} 
$values =$query| ForEach-Object{$_.Value} 
$nextLink= $query | Select-Object -Property '@odata.nextlink'

$folders = $values | Select-Object -Property DisplayName

$results = foreach($folder in $folders){
    $DisplayName = $folder.DisplayName

    Write-Host "CLIENT: $DisplayName"
}
if($nextLink.'@odata.nextLink'){
    $apiURL=$nextLink.'@odata.nextLink'.ToString()
}


}while($nextLink.'@odata.nextLink')
```

And if you track the request with the ‘nextlink’, you will find that the pattern of the next link is using the ‘skip’ and ‘top’ to get the page from the collection. Here is an figure for your reference:
[image]

Comment: perfect. thanks for the help! I really appreciate it.